# Download multiple images at once (with ID from 1 to x in the URL)

Tags: linux, open-source, download-manager

I need a solution for downloading multiple images at once. It must work in GNU/Linux and it must only involve free/libre software. I would prefer a stand-alone program (command-line or GUI), but a browser extension is fine, too.

The image URLs have a number in the query component, from 1 to *n*:

```
http://example.com/path?query&id=1&foo=bar
http://example.com/path?query&id=2&foo=bar
http://example.com/path?query&id=3&foo=bar
```

There is no page where all images are embedded/linked.

The user should

1. paste the first image URL,
2. mark where the ID in the query is (or how the parameter is called),
3. and enter how many images there are.

The program should

1. download all images,
2. and ideally include the ID in the file name (e.g., `1.png`, `2.png`, …).

Answer (score 5):

Good old [`wget`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) was pretty much made for this. ([`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) works, too.)

You just need to use a shell loop to invoke `wget` for each image. In Bash:

```
for N in {1..5} ; do wget "http://example.com/path?query&id=$N&foo=bar" -O $N.png ; done
```

Edit the range and the URL to taste. If there's an error trying to retrieve a given image, you'll see an error message and an empty file will be saved.